# Objective-c indexOfObject abnormal behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some problem consider indexOfObject method of the objective-C

I encounter a quite weird condition that when i use indexOfObject, and search a  string through the NSArray (that the string is not in my array),

In my iPad mini (iOS 10.3.3), the value return is -1,

while in my IPad2, the value return is 2147483647 (which is defined as NSNotFound),

May i ask if there are any reason concerning the behaviour of returning -1 from my iPad mini?

Comment: How did you defined the index? `NSUInteger` or `NSInteger`?

Comment: just defined as int to receive the result of indexOfObject

Comment: It means that , the object was not found in your Array, When your try to get index of object which is not available in array, the compiler will gives you max range value based on type.

Comment: "just defined as int to receive the result of indexOfObject" - and that's what you get when you try to stuff `NSIntegerMax` into `int`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: `NSInteger` is defined to be a 32-bit integer on 32-bit platforms, and a 64-bit integer on 64-bit platforms. `int`, however, is 32-bits on most platforms (and certainly all Apple platforms). Attempting to fit a max 64-bit integer into a 32-bit integer will cause this overflow. Redefine your variable to be `NSInteger` instead of `int`.

Comment: thanks and it seems to work fine when i change int to NSInteger